# What could be causing different plot styles when using different pandas dataframes and groupby?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, group-by

I use "df_combined.groupby('date')['car_count'].plot(legend = True)" to plot line chart.When use
the other df(just different name from df_combined), it shows different plot style.[The bottom image is what I want, but it will show the above image.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6yzkw.jpg)

I thought it was a time series problem, but after looking at the details of the two df, I found that the contents were identical.[the pic shows the two df I use to plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rBRRY.jpg)

```
for j in range(3):
    date_offset = pd.DateOffset(days=-j)
    query_date_start = pd.to_datetime(datatime).date() + date_offset
    query_date_end = pd.to_datetime(datatime).date() + date_offset + pd.DateOffset(days=1)
    query = f'''SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME((UNIX_TIMESTAMP(JGSJ) DIV 900)*900) as time_slot, COUNT(*) as car_count
            FROM rbx_rec_video_gcjl
            WHERE JGSJ >= '{query_date_start}' AND JGSJ < '{query_date_end}'
            AND CROSS_NO = '{device_id}'
            GROUP BY FROM_UNIXTIME((UNIX_TIMESTAMP(JGSJ) DIV 900)*900)
            '''
    df = pd.read_sql(query, cnx)
    df['time_slot'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time_slot'], format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')
    df_combined = pd.concat([df_combined, df])
    df_combined['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df_combined['time_slot']).dt.date
    year = query_date_start.year
    month = query_date_start.month
    day = query_date_start.day
    start_hour = 0
    start_minute = 0
    start_second = 0
    end_hour = 23
    end_minute = 45
    end_second = 0
    start_time = datetime(year, month, day, start_hour, start_minute, start_second)
    end_time = datetime(year, month, day, end_hour, end_minute, end_second)
    time_range = pd.date_range(start=start_time, end=end_time, freq='15min')
    reference_df = pd.DataFrame({'time_slot': time_range})
    merged_df = reference_df.merge(df_combined, on='time_slot', how='outer', sort=True)
    merged_df['car_count'] = merged_df['car_count'].fillna(0)
    # merged_df['time_slot'] = pd.to_datetime(merged_df['time_slot'], format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')
    merged_df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(merged_df['time_slot']).dt.date
final_df = merged_df.groupby('date')
sorted_categories = final_df.groups.keys()
sorted_categories = sorted(sorted_categories, reverse=True)
sorted_df = merged_df.set_index('date').loc[sorted_categories].reset_index()
sorted_df.groupby('date')['car_count'].plot(legend = True)
```

Comment: Can you share some code so we can see how you are generating the plots?